# What is the use of Strings._i() in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I'm new to flutter I got this example from github but I don't know what is the exact usage of `Strings._i();` this thing

github link : https://github.com/dhola-hardik/flutter_getx_example/blob/main/lib/res/strings.dart

```
Strings strings = Strings();

final title = "Strings";

class Strings {
  static final Strings _strings = Strings._i();

  factory Strings() {
    return _strings;
  }

  Strings._i();

  final String app_name = 'Flutter GetX Example';
  final String welcome = 'Welcome';
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this line  `static final Strings _strings = Strings._i();` i don't know why this line was used.

Answer (score 4):

That is `named constructor`, start with `_` make it private.

In your case, it is use for create a `singleton` class, make this class accessible from anywhere and only have 1 instance of this class at a time

Comment: what is the purpose of this line  `static final Strings _strings = Strings._i();`  I don't know why this line was used.

Comment: @KumaresanJackie use for store singleton instance that created by named constructor and return by default constructor factory. then every time we call `Strings()` insteads of create **new Strings**, it return old instance of **Strings**.